# Parameter type mismatch:Expression must be rvalue

Tags: c++, clion, type-mismatch, rvalue

```
string operator+(string str1, string str2)
{
    string thisValue = str1;
    return string(thisValue.append(str2));
}
```

link to jpg: https://puu.sh/z06u7/57d8129c24.png

I work with: CLion2017.2.3

I have an error: "Parameter type mismatch:Expression must be rvalue"

I'd appreciate if someone could explain me why I can cast string this way:
*(string)"example"*  but I cannot do it here.

Program is working anyway so I assume it's just compiler fixing this error but it really bothers me.

Could it be IDE bug? (I found some similar topics but it was said that it had been fixed)

Comment: *"Program is working anyway"* It sounds like you are able to compile and execute successfully, so where or when does this error occur?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Just CLion mark it as an error. It compiles without any Exceptions. I wouldn't make big fuss about it but teacher asked me to explain this error and i'm not able to.

Comment: You can simplify that to `return str1.append(str2);`.

Comment: CLion does occasionally produce wrong inspection errors. Its inspection is useful, but you'll get false positives some times. Turn on all your compiler warnings and go by that when in doubt.